# sys.stdout.write() printing at wrong time with pipelines in Python

Tags: python, stdout, pipeline

I'm having a problem in a homework assignment related to printing using the sys.stdout.write() function. What I have to do is to implement a simple shell which supports stdin/stdout redirections and pipelines. In the code below, from my program "ch.py", the problem is that the "%% " asking for an input seems to be printed at the wrong time when the expression entered contains a pipeline.

For example, if I enter "find -name ch.py | xargs grep import", what I want to get is:

```
%% find -name ch.py | xargs grep import
import os
import sys
import shlex
%%
```

But what I actually get is:

```
%% find -name ch.py | xargs grep import
%% import os
import sys
import shlex
```

Since the problem is not present when the input contains no pipeline as in "ls" or "cat ch.py", I suppose that my main process doesn't wait for all child processes to complete before continuing. I tried calling "os.waitpid()" with other combinaisons of arguments or using "os.wait()" instead but nothing seems to fix the problem.

Could someone help me understand what I'm wrong about?

```
import os
import sys
import shlex


def main():
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write("%% ")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        user_input = sys.stdin.readline()

        if user_input:
            parsed_input, to_write = parse(user_input)
        else:  # user pressed Ctrl+D, exit program
            sys.stdout.write("Bye!\n")
            sys.exit(0)

        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:  # EVALUATION PROCESS
            if to_write:              # if stdout redirection
                os.dup2(to_write, 1)  # write in file instead of stdout
                os.close(to_write)

            evaluate(parsed_input, len(parsed_input)-1)
        elif pid > 0:  # MAIN PROCESS
            os.waitpid(pid, 0)  # wait for evaluation to complete


def evaluate(parsed_input, pipe_count):
    if pipe_count == 0:
        # execute leftmost command of the expression
        os.execvp(parsed_input[0][0], parsed_input[0])
    elif pipe_count > 0:
        r, w = os.pipe()

        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:  # CHILD
            os.close(w)
            os.dup2(r, 0)  # read from pipeline instead of stdin
            os.close(r)
            # execute right side of the pipeline
            os.execvp(parsed_input[-1][0], parsed_input[-1])
        elif pid > 0:  # PARENT
            os.close(r)
            os.dup2(w, 1)  # write in pipeline instead of stdout
            os.close(w)
            # evaluate left side of the pipeline
            evaluate(parsed_input[:-1], pipe_count-1)
```

Comment: You should wait for pids resulting from `os.fork()` in `evaluate()` too. You call `waitpid()` only for the first fork in `main()`, so if `pipe_count` > 0, you fail to wait any of the processes created in `evaluate()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After inverting what's done by the parent and the child in `evaluate`, I was able to make the parent wait for all the children to complete and the problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here the fixed code, thank you again Sami Laine.

```
def evaluate(parsed_input, pipe_count):
    if pipe_count == 0:
        # execute leftmost command of the expression
        os.execvp(parsed_input[0][0], parsed_input[0])
    elif pipe_count > 0:
        r, w = os.pipe()

        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:  # CHILD
            os.close(r)
            os.dup2(w, 1)  # write in pipeline instead of stdout
            os.close(w)
            # evaluate left side of the pipeline
            evaluate(parsed_input[:-1], pipe_count-1)
        elif pid > 0:  # PARENT
            os.close(w)
            os.dup2(r, 0)  # read from pipeline instead of stdin
            os.close(r)
            os.waitpid(pid, 0)  # wait for children to complete
            # execute right side of the pipeline
            os.execvp(parsed_input[-1][0], parsed_input[-1])
```